# How does this method of removing an element from a stack work?

Tags: c++, vector, element

I just started taking a C++ class at my local college and the instructor gave the class an assignment in which we must create a vector and remove an element from the middle of the stack.

She provided this example:

```
vect[3] = vect[vect.size()-1];
vect.pop_back();
```

Now.. I've tested it and it works I'm just unsure how it works or why it works. I'm sure someone could provide a simple explanation?

Comment: Note that the example is not possible with only stack operations (push and pop).  To erase an element in the middle of a stack, you'd need to create a new stack, pop-push elements to the new stack, pop the element you want to remove, and pop-push them back to the original..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to delete an element from the middle of the vector, so you simply overwrite it with the last element (with index `size()-1`) - since the last element thus becomes redundant, we can `pop_back()` it. Finally we have the desired result - the vector size is decreased by one and the old value at `vect[3]` is gone.

*Note that this doesn't preserve the order of elements in the vector, but it is relatively efficient* - erasing from the middle of a vector may involve a lot of memory copying since all elements after the element to be deleted need to be shifted by one to accommodate the gap (remember: a `std::vector` stores its elements in continuous storage). Erasing from the end costs almost nothing.